# Sorting and comparing Java Date objects produces unexpected results

Tags: java, date, locale

I have a number of java Date objects which I am attempting to sort in ascending date order.

These are loaded from a CSV using a simple date formatter in UK format "dd/mm/yy HH:ss", and output in the same format, e.g.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy HH:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

This works correctly.

However, when I attempt to sort these (by implementing the Comparator interface) these are sorted incorrectly seemingly in US date format (mm/dd/yy).

```
    public int compare(CSVEntry t, CSVEntry t1) {
        if (t.date.before(t1.date))
            return -1;
        else if (t.date.after(t1.date))
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

This is regardless of what method I use (Date.after() or Date.before() or Date.compareTo) and regardless of what the locale is set to.

I've attempted to set the system default local using:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

To no effect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
"dd/mm/yy HH:ss"
```

`mm` is minutes of the hour. You are probably looking for `MM` (month of the year).

Also, `HH:ss`? Not `HH:mm` or `HH:mm:ss`?

Answer (score 0):

If `t.date` is actually a `Date` object then the format of your input is irrelevant. It will compare the fields of the `Date` object itself.

Hence it's almost certainly a problem with how you converted your text date to a `Date` object.

I think you need to debug *that* process and find out why (or if) the date is being converted incorrectly.

For a start, the format you should be using is:

```
dd/MM/yy HH:ss
```

The lower case `m` (as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)) is for minutes rather than months. I'm assuming your rather "strange" `HH:ss` is what you want even though it doesn't have the minutes specifier.

You may want to check that as well.